# The WebScraper is not running

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, urllib

I am using `BeautifulSoup` for scraping the Nasdaq site. Using the code below,

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname= False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

sym = input('Enter Ticker: ').upper()
ur = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?symbol='
url = ur+sym

html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

The problem is the the moment I run this code, it hangs.
Like it doesn't do anything just stops there.
I was entering the ticker as msft for microsoft.
I need to know if my code has any error. And if not, then why the code is not running.

Comment: The above code is created in pyhton

Answer (score 1):

Just add headers:

```
headers = {
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Full code:

```
import requests

sym = input('Enter Ticker: ')
url = f"https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?symbol={sym}"

headers = {
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: How would you explain, why you did that? I mean why did you put `headers`?

Comment: I opened the site in the browser, looked at what is required to get the page